# ¿Cómo ordenar una lista de archivos seleccionado parte de la cadena? En java

Tags: java

espero que me puedan ayudar. Tengo al rededor de 2000 archivos xml almacenados en un directorio cuya estructura de nombre está conformada de la siguiente forma "id_rfc_fecha.xml", es decir,

```
"arq_rfc_2018-01-07.xml"
"psf_rfc_2018-03-09.xml"
"qlf_rfc_2018-01-02.xml"
"srq_rfc_2018-01-11.xml"
```

Automáticamente los ordena de forma alfabética, lo que se requiere es ordenarlos por fecha, ejemplo:

```
"qlf_rfc_2018-01-02.xml"
"arq_rfc_2018-01-07.xml"
"srq_rfc_2018-01-11.xml"
"psf_rfc_2018-03-09.xml"
```

Les proporciono el código hasta dónde me quede. Muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
package inicio;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class listOrdenada {
    private static Scanner op;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        op = new Scanner(System.in);
        String suc = "";
        String mes = "";
        System.out.print("Introduce mes a buscar: ");
        //mes = op.next();
        mes="Septiembre";
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Introduce la Sucursal a Buscar: ");
        suc = op.next();
        String path = "/database/cores/2018/" +mes+ "/xml/";
        //System.out.print(path);
        String[] files = getFiles(path);
        if (files != null) {
            int size = files.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                // System.out.println(files[ i ].substring(46) );
                if (files[i].contains(suc.toUpperCase())) {
                    System.out.println(files[i].substring(47));
                }            
            }
        }
    }
    public static  String[] getFiles(String dir_path) {
        String[] arr_res = null;
        File f = new File(dir_path);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            ArrayList<Object> res = new ArrayList<>();
            File[] arr_content = f.listFiles();
            int size = arr_content.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                if (arr_content[i].isFile()&& new EvaluaExtension().accept(arr_content[i], ".xml"))
                    res.add(arr_content[i].toString());
                    }
            arr_res = res.toArray(new String[0]);
        } else
            System.err.println("¡ Directorio NO válido !");


        return arr_res;

    }
}
        class EvaluaExtension implements FilenameFilter {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String extension) {
                return dir.getName().endsWith(extension);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí mi solución utilizando *Java 8*.

Primero lo que hago es crear un método para recuperar la fecha desde el nombre del archivo y la convierto en una un objeto de la clase `LocalDate`.

```
public static LocalDate extractAndConvert(String filename){
    int start = filename.lastIndexOf("_") + 1;
    int end = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    String date = filename.substring(start, end);
    return LocalDate.parse(date);
}
```

Seguido utilizo el método `Arrays.sort` donde le mando como primer parámetro el *array* de archivos y como segundo parámetro `Comparator.comparing` que será el encargado de indicar con que clave realizar el ordenamiento.

```
public static void orderByLocalDate() {
    File[] files = {
            new File("qlf_rfc_2016-01-02.xml"), new File("arq_rfc_2015-01-07.xml"),
            new File("srq_rfc_2018-01-11.xml"), new File("psf_rfc_2020-03-09.xml")
    };
    showFiles(files);
    Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing(o -> extractAndConvert(o.getName())));
    // También se pudo haber utilizado la siguiente línea:
    // Arrays.sort(files, (o1, o2) -> extractAndConvert(o1.getName()).compareTo(extractAndConvert(o2.getName())));
    showFiles(files);
}
```

El método arrojara lo siguiente:

```
// Antes de ordenar
qlf_rfc_2016-01-02.xml
arq_rfc_2015-01-07.xml
srq_rfc_2018-01-11.xml
psf_rfc_2020-03-09.xml

// Después de ordenar
arq_rfc_2015-01-07.xml
qlf_rfc_2016-01-02.xml
srq_rfc_2018-01-11.xml
psf_rfc_2020-03-09.xml
```

En caso de requerir el ordenamiento de forma inversa puedes añadir un segundo parámetro al método `Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor, Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)` de la siguiente forma:

```
Arrays.sort(files, Comparator.comparing(o -> extractAndConvert(o.getName()), Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Por último el método `showFiles` solamente muestra el nombre de los archivos en el *array*:

```
private static void showFiles(File[] files) {
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
}
```

Enlaces a la documentación oficial de las clases principales:

- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)
- [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)
- [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)